# How to search through pnp only for one site page rather than the site

Tags: sharepoint, kql

what is the search  query  to given in my sharepoint pnp result to search on particular document library in my share point page as a web part

when i tried adding pnp search result web part, the result was showing all over files in the site, but i need the results from a particualr document library

Comment: what's your status, did you try my solution in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter on the `Path` managed property with the beginning of the absolute path of your document library.

For example:

```
{searchTerms} Path:https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/your-library
```

Comment: Hi Jleture, i have tried but i is not working

Comment: What’s the result? No result? Error? Can you add screenshots of your configuration? You can also try with a * at the end of the Path.